# Codility PermMissingElem solution estimated complexity

Tags: c++, permutation

After toying around with this exercise for a while I have figured out a fool-proof (no buffer overflow and such) algorithm as below:

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    long long sum = 0;
    int size = A.size();
    if (size == 0) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        sum = sum + i+1 - A[i];
    }

    sum += size+1;

    if (sum == 0) 
        return (size+1);
    else
        return sum;
}
```

However, the detected Time complexity given by Codility is:

```
Detected time complexity:
O(N) or O(N * log(N))
```

From my code, **I do not see** why it would be `O(N * log(N))`. If you have any explanation, I will be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Just a result of `detected` complexity.

Comment: I don't see how this can be anything but O(N). Perhaps it's difficult for whatever automated measuring system they are using to decide between the two given measurement error?

Comment: Yes, I'm also inclined to think it's a time measurement error and not the result of a proper code analysis. But I'm still open for answers.

Comment: I am nearly sure it is a measurement problem, but its not an error it says OR. The reason it says OR it cannot detect which one of those it is, simply because the input size is to small to distinguish between those two functions, which are both growing slowly.

Comment: @pipa, I also believe this is O(n).